# enter server in sql drop down list

Tags: sql

I am working with Sql and when I log in I see server lists in drop down. How can I add a new server to that drop down list? I am told that I have access to the other server and I only need to "enter it". thanks

I searched and could not find how to add a new server to my sql login page drop down list

Comment: what tool are you using ?

Comment: Is this really related to the SQL _language_?

Comment: Hi Don, I use SQL Server Mng Studio

Comment: Yes Jarlh, it is